# VBA Code does not return any value or either give an error; user-define

Tags: vba, ms-access, search, listbox

Here's my code: It should return the results from search filed in msaccess text box list. Search criteria is separated with " , "
I am trying to search multiple part numbers.

```vb
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command7_Click()

End Sub

Public Sub btnSearch2_Click()
    Dim ArrayList() As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rstSearchResults As ADODB.Recordset
    
    ' Split the parameter values by comma and store them in an array
    ArrayList = Split(Me.txtSearchCriteria2.Value, ",")
    
    ' Construct the SQL query
    strSQL = "SELECT CSP_Data.Manufacturer_Part_Number, CSP_Data.CSP_Number, CSP_Data.Rec_Min_Qty, CSP_Data.CSP_Type " & _
             "FROM CSP_Data " & _
             "WHERE Manufacturer_Part_Number ILike '*" & Me.txtSearchCriteria2.Value & "*'"
    
    ' Create a new recordset
    Set rstSearchResults = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    ' Open the recordset based on the SQL query
    rstSearchResults.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    
    ' Bind the list box to the recordset
    Me.lstSearchResults2.RowSource = rstSearchResults
    
    ' Requery the list box to display the data
    Me.lstSearchResults2.Requery
    
    ' Clean up
    rstSearchResults.Close
    Set rstSearchResults = Nothing
End Sub
```

tried getting this code fixed from chatgpt but its not useful. i still dont get any response

Comment: What is `ILike`?

Comment: Does `Me.txtSearchCriteria2.Value` contain a single quote character?

Comment: No, its for multiple characters separated by ","

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `where` clauses one-by-one:

```vb
Dim el, sep As String, arraylist, rstSearchResults 

arraylist = Split(Me.txtSearchCriteria2.Value, ",")

strSQL = " SELECT CSP_Data.Manufacturer_Part_Number, CSP_Data.CSP_Number, " & _
         " CSP_Data.Rec_Min_Qty, CSP_Data.CSP_Type " & _
         " FROM CSP_Data WHERE "
         
For Each el In arraylist
    If Len(Trim(el)) > 0 Then
        strSQL = strSQL & sep & "Manufacturer_Part_Number Like '*" & Trim(el) & "*' "
        sep = " or " 'populate or after first iteration
    End If
Next el

Set rstSearchResults = New ADODB.Recordset
rstSearchResults.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please flag as "Accepted", to help anyone else who has a similar problem.

Comment: If a user types an apostrophe in the search box, your query will fail.

Comment: …so watch out for that!